# Postscript: how to use setdash as a clipping path

Tags: postscript

I have a path and I can use setdash. It works.

What I need to do is convert the dashes to be clipping path. I.e. the clipping path should be a series of boxes and arcs (path is curved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strokepath` and `clip` Eg:

```
%!
10 10 moveto
[3 3] 0 setdash
10 500 lineto
strokepath
clip
0 0 100 500 rectfill
showpage
```

Comment: This looks awesomely straightforward. Many thanks Ken. I'm going to try this shortly.

Comment: Brilliant Ken. Works great  :)